# Email masking Regex Kotlin

Tags: android, regex, kotlin, email, mask

all. I want to mask email and am having a little problem.

> **My code**

```
val email = lucyrocher@gmail.com
val p = """^([^@]{2})([^@]+)""".toRegex()
val result = email.replace(p) {
 it.groupValues[1] + "*".repeat(it.groupValues[2].length)
}
```

> **expected result**  : mask with * for first two letters && first four letters after @

```
lu********@****l.com
```

> **current result** : can mask before @ but not after it

```
lu********@gmail.com
```

**How can I mask the first 4 letters after @?**

Comment: if I suggest, you can do this without regex as well. split the string with email.split("@").. you will two strings, one before @ & second after it... you can then directly perform operation on them

Comment: Thanks @SakshamKhurana! Now I solved the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who will see this post later, here I share my code.

> **Email Mask** : lu********@****l.com

```
val regex = """^([^@]{2})([^@]+)([^@]{0}@)([^@]{4})""".toRegex()
val emailMask = args.biometricOtp.otpData.replace(regex) {
    it.groupValues[1] + "*".repeat(it.groupValues[2].length) 
  + it.groupValues[3] + "*".repeat(it.groupValues[4].length) }
```

> **Phone number Mask** : 82103*******

```
val regex = """([^@]{5})([^@]+)""".toRegex()
val smsMask = args.biometricOtp.otpData.replace(regex) {
    it.groupValues[1] + "*".repeat(it.groupValues[2].length) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all chars with `*` that match the following pattern:

```
(?:\G(?!^)|(?<=^[^@]{2}|@))[^@](?!\.[^.]+$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hfw8uf/1). *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|(?<=^[^@]{2}|@))` - match `@` (with `@`), or start of string and any two chars other than `@` (with `(?<=^[^@]{2}`), or the end of the previous successful match (with `\G(?!^)`)
- `[^@]` - any one char other than a `@`
- `(?!\.[^.]+$)` - that is not immediately followed with a `.` and then one or more chars other than `.` till the end of string.

See the [Kotlin demo](https://ideone.com/2k43Jr):

```kotlin
val regex = """(?:\G(?!^)|(?<=^[^@]{2}|@))[^@](?!\.[^.]+$)""".toRegex()
val email = "lucyrocher@gmail.com"
val emailMask = email.replace(regex, "*")
print(emailMask)
// => lu********@****l.com
```

Comment: @Lucy Thank you comments are off-topic and are subsequently removed. Please see SO help what to do when you want to thank a user who provided a helpful solution.